# Password on c# Button

Tags: c#, validation, button, authentication, passwords

I have a windows form i'm working on. I have a button on a windows form if a user clicks the button another window appears with a textbox and a button asking you to put a password in.
If the user types the passord correctly it will open a new form called AdminPage, however if the user types in the incorrect password a messagebox appears asking to try again. The problem is that i cant seem to get the AdminPage to open even if I type in the correct password.
If someone could guide me in my errors that would be great thanks

```
 private void EnterBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (PsswdTxt.Text == ("BuildStore"))
        {
            AdminPage m = new AdminPage();
            m.Show();
            this.Close();
        }
          else

                MessageBox.Show("Please Try again");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After clicking on button,does the application get closed if password is correct?

Comment: No the messagebox appears and says please try again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that you're typing Buildstore or buildStore?  The comparison is case sensitive - if you want to match the word irrespective of case you can use [String.Compare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkcaxw5y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or you could convert both values to upper/lower:

```
if (string.Compare(PsswdTxt.Text,"BuildStore" ,true) == 0) // true signifies to ignore case
{
   AdminPage m = new AdminPage();
   m.Show();
   this.Visible = false;
}
```

or...

```
   if (PsswdTxt.Text.ToUpper() == "BuildStore".ToUpper())
    {
       AdminPage m = new AdminPage();
       m.Show();
       this.Visible = false;
    }
```

Comment: Might I add that ignoring case in a password check is a bad idea?

Comment: You're welcome.  @germi - I agree, though I don't know the OPs business requirements and I'm just highlighting a fix if it is to be case insensitive comparison.

Answer (score 0):

try this code..

```
 private void EnterBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.Equals(PsswdTxt.Text,"BuildStore"))
        {
            AdminPage m = new AdminPage();
            m.Show();
            this.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
          MessageBox.Show("Please Try again");
        }        
    }
```

Comment: This gives me the same results "Please try again"

Comment: have you tried to debug your code? Add watch on `PasswdTxt.Text` and on `string.Equals(PsswdTxt.Text,"BuildStore")` . PasswdTxt.Text should be equal to BuildStore and string.Equals(PsswdTxt.Text,"BuildStore") must be true, try to debug the code and check both watches

Answer (score 0):

You should try ShowDialog instead of Show. It might be that it is shown behind the other form.